# Selenium for Python - text_to_be_present for partial text matching

Tags: python, selenium

I have a div which contains the results for a certain search query. The text contained in this div changes as a button to go to the next page is clicked.

In the text contained in this div, there is also the corresponding number of the page. After clicking in the button to go to the next page, the results still take a bit to load, so I want to make the driver wait the content to load.

As such, I want to wait until the string "Page x" appears inside the div, where x corresponds to the number of the next page to be loaded.

For this, I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Search page
driver.get('http://searchpage.com')

timeout = 120
current_page = 1

while True:
    try:
        # Wait until the results have been loaded
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
                locator=(By.ID, "SEARCHBASE"),
                text_="Page {:}".format(current_page)))

        # Click to go to the next page. This calls some javascript.
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="#"]').click

        current_page += 1
    except:
        driver.quit()
```

Although, this always fails to match the text. What am I doing wrong here?

To just detect if anything whatsoever had changed in the page would also do the job, but I haven't found any way to do that.

Comment: Do you mean that the full text content of `div#SEARCHFORMBASE` is `"some text Page 1"`, `"some text Page 2"`... ?

Comment: @Andersson yes. There's also some more text after 'Page x'

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply below solution to wait for partial text match:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(lambda driver: "Page {:}".format(current_page) in driver.find_element(By.ID, "SEARCHBASE").text)
```

Comment: It also doesn't catch the change

Comment: Did you get timeout exception?